# Why does "calculate" button remain gray in Group Stats Plugin?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I'm trying to use the Group Stats Plugin.

Unfortunately I can not use the plugin: after I enter all the required values, press "calculate" is not active and is always gray.

My problem is that I have a shape of point that are points for animal sightings.  This shape is formed by a text field containing the types of areas (beech, poplar, etc.) and another containing the areas value.
I need to calculate the number of records that contains a precise type of vegetation and the sum of the relative areas.

Is this possible with Group Stats Plugin?